# How to add a Django form field through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a Django form like this:

```
class CrawlRequest(models.Model):
    tor_info = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

My view is like this:

```
def create_crawl(response):
    context = {}
    if response.method == "POST":
        my_form = RawCrawlRequestForm(response.POST)
        if my_form.is_valid():
            new_crawl = CrawlRequestForm(my_form.cleaned_data)
            new_crawl.save()
            return render(response, "main/steps_creation.html", context)
    else:
        my_form = RawCrawlRequestForm()

    context['form'] = my_form
    return render(response, "main/create_crawl.html", context)
```

And I have my template, where I have a Select that calls a JavaScript function like this when changed:

```
function detailIpRotationType(){
    var ipSelect = document.getElementById("ip_type");
    const ip_rotation_type = ipSelect.options[ipSelect.selectedIndex].value;
    var extra_div = document.getElementById("ip_type_div");

    if(ip_rotation_type == 'tor'){
        extra_div.innerHTML = `
        <input class="form-control" name="tor_info" id="tor_info" type="text" required/>
        `
    }
```

This works fine, but I want to change this input element to {{ forms.tor_info }}. When I add it normally just like I do in my main template, it isn't recognized as a Django element, and it becomes a text.

Does anybody know how can I do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The {{variables}} and the script using (.innerHTML) cant work together in one file. If you want to use innerHTML you should put your code in the js file and then refer the id to html file.

And if you want to put the {{variables}} and the script together in one file, you should use the hidden input field to get a value in javascript.

In the Django side, what do you return? did you return render(), or did you define a function?

Check this link as well, it may help:

https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/02/18/safely-including-data-for-javascript-in-a-django-template/

Comment: Hi @noone! I return render() in my view. I will check out this reference and try what you suggested. Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: I see you should update your question and add your view return function. It would be clear